# Abstract Syntax Tree in compiler: how exactly to represent a function?

Tags: c, regex, bison, abstract-syntax-tree

We're creating a very simple programming language, using Flex and Bison for parsing and syntax analysis, and using C to build the compiler.
Before going straight to assembly, we're creating an abstract syntax tree from the language rules. But we're having trouble representing one specific function from the language.
The function is described as follows:

> FILTERC: It takes a condition and an expression list as input and it returns how many of those expressions match the condition. It can be a single or compund condition.
>   It is used in this form: **FILTERC (condition, [expression list])**
>   The condition has to have an underscore before each element, representing where the expressions should be placed for comparison. Example: **FILTERC ( _>4 and _<=6.5 , [a+c,b,c-a,d])**

This is how the "filterc" function is expressed in BNF rules (we actually used tokens with Flex, but I simplified it with the actual characters since that's not the point and the syntax analysis is correctly done by Bison):

```
filter ::= FILTERC ( condition_filter , [ expression_list ] )
;
condition_filter ::= comparison_filter | comparison_filter AND comparison_filter | comparison_filter OR comparison_filter
;
comparison_filter ::= _ > expression | _ < expression | _ == expression | _ >= expression | _ <= expression | _ != expression
;
expression_list ::= expression | expression , expression_list
;
expression: term | expression + term | expression - term
;
term: factor | term * factor | term / factor 
;
factor: ID | INT_LITERAL | REAL_LITERAL | STRING_LITERAL | ( expression ) | filter
;
```

We now have to write functions that create the nodes of the abstract syntax tree. At low level, the "filterc" function is nothing but a bunch of "IF" to verify that each one of the expressions matches the condition, only that now the expressions will be placed where the underscore is. So it would be something like: *(expression) (comparison operator) (condition)*

The thing is, the actual FILTERC sentence is read "backwards": the expressions are read first and then compared to the condition. But the program is read sequentially: the underscore is read before the actual expression is found. So we're really confused as to how to build the tree.

I'm not going to add all the code we use to create the nodes and leaves of the tree or this would be a total mess. But basically, there is a function that creates nodes with 2 children (left and right) and when there shouldn't be any children, those pointers are set to null. The basic structure we use is to place the operator in the root node and the operands as the children (e.g.: in an "if" sentence, the "if" keyword should be the root, the condition would be the left child and the code block to execute if true would be the right child). Like this:

```
IF condition THEN block {thenPtr = blockPtr;} ENDIF {createNode("if", conditionPtr, thenPtr);}
```

("condition" and "block" are defined elsewhere, where their pointers are created).

We were able to successfully create the tree for the expression regex and for all the other rules in the language, but this "filter" function is really confusing.

Comment: Why are you concerned about the order in which the (sub)AST trees are built?  Your problem in parsing with ASTs is to capture what has been parsed.  The purpose of the AST is represent the captured result; it can be processed later in any order you like (unlike parsing which is left to right).   So... build your AST nodes for the filter condition (you clearly know how do that by attaching actions to rules), and build your AST nodes for the expressions (by attaching actions to rules), and then run the resulting parser.  This should produce a full AST with both filter condition and expressions.

Comment: Thanks, Ira. But I still don't get it: when the parser reads the rule `filter::=FILTERC(condition_filter, [expression_list])` it will go sequentially so it will try to determine what a `condition_filter` is. It will see that a condition_filter can be a comparison_filter, and this could be, for example: `comparison_filter ::= _ > expression`. So it needs to create a node with the operator (in this case, the > symbol), and left and right children with the expressions to compare. The problem is, it doesn't have the left side expression yet, because it hasn't read it.

Comment: You should change the title of your question to something more like:  ".. how to build a tree using Bison?"

Answer (score 2):

It is true that when the parser reads a piece of an expression (e.g., the ">"), it hasn't got enough to build the tree for the expression. That same is true for any concept ("nonterminal") in your language. And from that perspective I see you you can be confused.

Apparantly you don't understand how LR parsers like Bison work. Assume we have rules R1, R2, ... with rules have right hand sides, e.g.,  Rn = T1 T2 T3 ; with each rule having a right hand side length of L(Rn).

The key idea that you need, is that an LR parser collects ("stacks", yes it really uses a stack of tokens) tokens from the input stream, left to right.  These steps are called "shifts".  The parser shifts repeatedly, continually looking for situations which indicate that enough tokens have been read (e.g., T1, T2, then T3) to satisfy the right hand side of some grammar rule Rn.  The magic of the parser generator and the LR tables it produces allows the parser to keep efficient track of all the "live" rules at once and we're not going to discuss that further here.

At the point where a right hand side for has been recognized at that point, the LR parser performs a "reduce" action and replaces the stacked tokens that match the body of the rule, with the nonterminal token Rn  ("pops the stack L(Rn) times then and pushes Rn").  It does as many reductions as it can, before returning to collecting terminal tokens from the input stream. *It is worth your trouble to simulate this process by hand on a really tiny grammar.* [A subtle detail: some rules have empty right hand sides, e.g., L(Rn)==0); in that case, when a reduction happens *zero* pops occur, yes that sounds funny but it is deadly right].

At every point where the parser does a reduce action, it offers you, the parser programmer, an opportunity to do some additional work.  That additional work is almost invariably "tree building".  Clearly, the tokens that make up the rule Rn have all been seen, so one can build a tree representing Rn if the tokens were all terminals. In fact, if all the tokens for Rn have been seen, and Rn contains some nonterminals, then there must have been reduce actions to produce each of the nonterminals.  If each of *them* produced a tree representing themselves, then when the rule containing the nonterminal is reduced, there are trees already produced for the other nonterminals, and these can be be combined to produce the tree for the current rule.

LR parser generator tools like Bison help you with, usually by providing tree-building operators that you can invoke in a reduce-action.  It also helps by making the trees for already processed nonterminals available to your reduce-action, so it can combine them to produce the tree for the reduce action.  (It does so by keeping track of generated trees in a stack parallel to the token stack. ) At no point does it ever attempt to reduce, or do you ever attempt to produce a tree, where you don't have all the subtrees needed.

I think you need to read the Bison manually *carefully* and all this will become clear, as you attempt to implement the parser and the reductions; the manual has good examples.   It is clear that you haven't done that (fear of not knowing how to handle the trees?), because a) your rules as expressed are broken; there's no way to generate a term, and b) you don't have any embedded reduce actions.